# kotlin - set aplha for views programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-view

I want to change alpha value of my views programmatically , it can easily be set via xml and it works fine , the value is between 0 to 1 and if I set it 0.5 in xml it semi transparent the view in my xml layout .

but how can I set it in kotlin ?

I've tried this code but it doesn't work at all :

```
ln.alpha = 0.5f
```

i've also tried to set value by integer ,someone said that it gets the value between 0 to 255 but when I set it , it shows me an error that the value is <=1

how can I dos o ?

Comment: Pragmatically or programmatically?

Comment: where do you put the code "ln.alpha = 0.5f" ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of `alpha` you can set

1. **Alpha on View**

> Sets the opacity of the view to a value from 0 to 1, where 0 means the
>   view is completely transparent and 1 means the view is completely
>   opaque.

```
view.alpha = 0.5f
```

2. **Alpha on Drawable**

> Specify an alpha value for the drawable. 0 means fully transparent,
>   and 255 means fully opaque.

```
view.background.alpha = 128
```

Comment: @NavidAbutorab, Have you checked that?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
open fun setAlpha(alpha: Float): Unit
```

Example:

```
view.setAlpha(0.6f);
```

Read more at: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View.html#setAlpha(kotlin.Float)

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
  views.setAlpha(0.5f); // for 50%
```

and if it is not worked use this one

```
views.getBackground().setAlpha(128);// for 50% and 256 for 100%
```